# Is Judas Iscariot ever depicted in religious art with one of those silver or gold coloured Halos?

Tags: symbolism, art, judas-iscariot

Is Judas Iscariot ever depicted in Religious art with one of those cool silver or gold coloured Halos?

> A halo also known as a nimbus, aureole, glory, or *gloriole* is a crown of light rays, circle or disk of light that surrounds a person in art. It has been used in the iconography of many religions to indicate holy or sacred figures, and has at various periods also been used in images of rulers or heroes. In the religious art of Ancient Greece, Ancient Rome, Christianity, Hinduism, and Buddhism among other religions, sacred persons may be depicted with a halo in the form of a circular glow, or flames in Asian art, around the head or around the whole body - this last one is often called a mandorla. Halos may be shown as almost any colour or combination of colours, but are most often depicted as golden, yellow or white when representing light or red when representing flames. - [Halo (religious iconography)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(religious_iconography))

Answer (score 1):

**Is Judas Iscariot ever depicted in religious art with one of those silver or gold coloured Halos?**

Judas Iscariot has never been portrayed wearing a halo of gold, silver, yellow or white to my knowledge.

But he has been portrayed wearing a **black** halo! Whatever that alludes too?

Amongst the numerous stained glass images in the [Church of St. John Baptist, Yeovil, England, there is one that depicts Judas Iscariot](http://www.yeovilhistory.info/stjohn.htm) with a black halo!

[image: In the Church of St John the Baptist, Yeovil, one stained glass window depicts Judas with a black halo.]

[In the Church of St John the Baptist, Yeovil, one stained glass window depicts Judas with a black halo.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/is-judas-iscariot-ever-depicted-in-catholic-art-with-one-of-those-silver-or-gold)

Wonder if this alludes to his being amongst the reprobates in Hell?

It is unusual to say the least.

Comment: It appears from the frame that Judas is extending his foot to be washed by Jesus. See that the table at which he is sitting has bread and wine on it. If Judas is a part of the group partaking in the Last Supper, we need to know if the others, including Jesus himself and the 11 apostles, have been shown with halo, and if so, of what colour. It is likely that the artist did not want to give the viewers the impression that he had left Judas out. Interestingly, the scripture says that Satan entered Judas after he had partaken of the meal. So, this could also be the 'shot ' taken at that time!

Comment: [**The color black**](https://www.joincake.com/blog/symbols-of-mourning/): “Of course, no list of the symbols relating to death would be complete without the color black. This is the color we wear to funerals in Western cultures. It’s dark, reflecting the dimming of the soul’s light as we fade into the afterlife.  Why is black associated so heavily with death? This is a practice that dates back to ancient times. In the Middle Ages and Victorian period, mourning clothes were always black to show an outward display of inner feelings of turmoil.”

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Judas is not extending his foot to be washed. It is obvious, he is getting ready to leave the table, for he has the common purse in his left hand (sinister). Judas was a thief and a betrayer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the purse. I wonder which is the larger painting that he is part of. Da Vinci also shows him walking out of the room..

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan, for the context, see [Yeovil's Virtual Museum, the A-to-Z of Yeovil's History - by Bob Osborn](http://www.yeovilhistory.info/windows.htm). The above image is "South Transept, south window, third light".  Judas (again with a black halo) also appears in "South Choir Aisle, south wall, east window, second light".  (Search for "Judas" on the page.)